# Best way to thread safe FindItemByText in listview

Tags: c#, search, thread-safety

I've been playing around with various ways of creating a function to cross thread search a ListView. Specifically using the method FindItemWithText and I've come up with a solution. I just don't believe its the right way to do it, any advice would be much appreciated

Current crude solution:

```
        string SearchLocal(string findstr)
    {
        string item = findstr;
        if (lvContactsLocal.InvokeRequired)
        {

                lvContactsLocal.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate ()
                {

                    if (lvContactsLocal.FindItemWithText(findstr, true, 0) != null)
                    {
                        item = lvContactsLocal.FindItemWithText(findstr, true, 0).Text;
                    }

                });

        }
        return item;
    }
```

It returns your input if it cant find a match in the listview

Comment: What is the purpose of the `if` statement? You could just do `item = lvContactsLocal.FindItemWithText(findstr, true, 0)?.Text ?? findstr;`

Comment: Why are your trying to use multiple threads?

Comment: it errors when it can't find an item hence the if statement I was unaware of ?? until now, thankyou :)

Comment: @Enigmativity I have a separate thread running that is making this method call. Need invoke otherwise its an unsafe and invalid

Comment: Why are you using separate threads?

Comment: one for gui one for the handling the socket connection